# Providing Apache Axis with a socketfactory object, not class

Tags: web-services, axis, socketfactory

In my current project, we are using Apache Axis to do remote calls via SOAP.

Now there are cases where the server host+port is not directly accessible due to firewall constraints, but there is the possibility of an SSH tunnel.

The [Axis documentation](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/integration-guide.html#PluggableAPIs) mentions the possibility to plug in an own [Socket factory](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/components/net/SocketFactory.html). But this plugging in only seems to be possible by providing the name of an implementation class in a System property.

I just spent a hour or such to implement a SocketFactory (via a custom SocketImpl implementation) based on a JSch session - but this SocketFactory object is dependent on a Session object, and can't be simply instantiated independently.

I think I could somehow solve this using static variables/methods, but this certainly does not look nice.

Actually, I want to be able to provide a new SocketFactory (with another base SSH Session) for every server (or group of servers), of which might exist several at the same time - thus, it would be necessary to provide this to the ServiceLocator.

Is there some way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open a permanent tunnel.
`ssh -L1337:127.0.0.1:8080 192.168.0.x`

and then connect to the local address (*127.0.0.1:1337*) as if it was remote.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't like the additional open port here (even if only on localhost), but I will use this (the JSch variant of this) if I don't find anything else.

Comment: I used this, thanks. If anyone finds a better idea, I'm still open.